# Curious Matplotlib tick label alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
x = range(26)
v = np.random.random(26)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.bar(x, v, width=0.8, align='center')

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(letters)
plt.savefig('so.eps')
```

Generates the figure below:
[image]

As you can see, the 'Q' is not aligned with the baseline properly and looks wrong.

Can anyone shed any light on this? If it's a bug in Matplotlib, is there a hack to get round it (e.g. by realigning a single xtick label)?

I have `text.usetex : True` in my `matplotlibrc` file, and the problem only seems to show when I save the figure as eps.

Comment: Seems to be os and/or font dependant. I run your code on Ubuntu 14.04 and Q looks in line with other letters, though the default font is different than yours. [generated plot](http://i.imgur.com/Pm9c2Lr.png)

Comment: Can you open a github issue with this example?

Comment: @tcaswell - OK, have done. I've corrected my question as well: I see the misaligned Q even with 4 bars.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if this is something that mpl _can_ fix or if this is going to be eps reader dependent.

Comment: Interestingly, if I run your sample code on Mint 17.3, `python 2.7.6` with `matplotlib (1.3.1-1ubuntu5)` and I **just use** `plt.show()` **instead of the EPS output** the Q is positioned slightly *lower* than the other characters. This happens with `ax.set_xticklabels(letters, verticalalignment = 'top')`, which seems to be the default. `verticalalignment = 'bottom'` works as intended, but that's not what OP wants. The `EPS` output looks fine here, but with a different font.